# In IntelliJ IDEA 9, how can I run an ant task after application run?

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

There is a "Run Ant target" option under "Before launch" in IntelliJ's Run/Debug Configurations. I wrote a script, to copy a file before the launch and on the other side, I need to delete this file after run. I can't find any option like "Run Ant target after run" in IntelliJ IDEA. Is it possible or is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in IDEA yet, Ant targets can be run on the following events:

- Before Compilation
- After Compilation
- Before Run/Debug

You can request new features in the [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).